# I created two Nintendo IDs and both have games linked to them... What do I do?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-network-id

I wanted to transfer my data from my old 3DS to my New 3DS xl, but I had no resources and I put it off. I had created a new Nintendo Network ID for my new 3DS and downloaded games onto it. However, I'm now able to recover the games from my old 3DS and put them on my New 3DS. However, I have a few concerns:

1. When transferring data, does the Nintendo Network ID on the old SD card override the one on the new SD card? If so, are all my linked games gone? Can I redownload them from my old ID?
2. Will my old Nintendo ID prevent me from redownloading titles on my new ID?

Thanks, and I hope to find some answers. This really worries me.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot combine NID accounts :/ you're going to have two 3DSs with your games split between them

Comment: My problem, sadly is that the original system that had the SD card can no longer function and I cannot do a direct transfer of data between the two.